# Avoid laravel sending two emails to same email address

Tags: php, laravel, validation, email

In my laravel application when a user register a company and once they get the account verification email, i'm trying to send them another email, saying their trial subscription period has been started.

For that, I have following function inside `createcompany.php`,

```
public function handle(Verified $event)
    {
        $company = $event->user?->companies()->first();

        if (!$company || $company->pivot_role === CompanyRolesEnum::EMPLOYEE->name || $company->isSubscribed()) return;

        CompanyStripeCustomer::createStripeAccount($company, $event->user);

        $companySubscription = (new CreateCompanyTrialSubscriptionAction)->execute($company);

        $company->companyPointOfContacts()
            ->each(fn($companyPointOfContact) => event(new SubscribedToTrialSubscription($companySubscription, $companyPointOfContact)));
    }
```

In my database I have a table called,company_point_of_contact. There I'm storing, two values primary contact and billing email. When a user registering with the system freshly, both values will be same.

Now initially, when an user verify their account, it is sending two emails to the same email address saying their trial period has started.... But I only need to send one email... How can I avoid the email duplication.

Following is my `SendSubscriptionTrailCreatedEmail.php`

```
class SendSubscriptionTrailCreatedEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param SubscribedToTrialSubscription $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SubscribedToTrialSubscription $event)
    {
        Mail::to($event->companyPointOfContact->value ?? $event->companyPointOfContact->user->email)
            ->send(new CompanyTrialSubscriptionEmail($event->companyPointOfContact->value, $event->companySubscription));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this line here

```
$company->companyPointOfContacts()
        ->each(fn($companyPointOfContact) => event(new SubscribedToTrialSubscription($companySubscription, $companyPointOfContact)));
```

will fire the event (n) of times - for each company point of contact-
you can check the relation to be one to one OR , just use first() and then fire the event once instead of firing it for each contact.

this is a create company function and I suppose it create one company at the  time.

Comment: If I need to remove the each, then how could i rewrite the line to fire an email only for one time...